# Read file and perform operation next line onwards after match

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, text, while-loop

I am trying to read a tab delimited text file into python. However the file have multiple subheadings. something like this:

```
a
[1,2,3]
[2,3,4]
[3,2,5,6]
b
[1,2,3]
[2,6,4]
[7,5,6]
```

i'm trying to write a function that takes the sub-headings as argument and perform a while loop until the next sub heading and return lines below the sub-heading as a list. In pseudocode, this is what i have in mind:

```
def func(sub-heading):
    outputlist = [ ]
    with open(filepath) as file:
        for line in file:
            if sub-heading:
                go next line 
                while not sub-heading:
                    outputlist.append(line.rstrip())
    return outputlist
```

So if i call func(a), i would get the list

```
[ [1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,2,5,6] ]
```

But i cant find a way to make the look go into the next line once it found the sub heading.

Any help will be appreciated

Edit for more information

Comment: clarify if that is actual format of data `[1,2,3]` and post the expected result

Comment: I've added some details. Please take a look

Comment: the final expected output is still is not presented in the question description

Comment: It is, 3rd code block. When i call a the function for a sub heading i want a list of the lines under that sub heading.

Answer (score 1):

For the given example the following will work. This prints only the lines that are not subheadings:

```
import re


def func():
    pattern = re.compile("\[(.*)\]")
    with open('your_file.txt', 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            if not pattern.match(line):
                continue  # this is the subheading
            else:
                print(line)


func()
```

Given the `your_file.txt` as follows:

```
a
[1,2,3]
[2,3,4]
[3,2,5,6]
b
[1,2,3]
[2,6,4]
[7,5,6]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this prints all lines except sub headings. I need to separate the lines by sub headings. I.e, each sub-heading needs to produce an individual list.